# Getting 403-status response when get requesting from website?

Tags: python, python-requests

i try to do a site request using the following code:

```
import requests

if __name__ == '__main__':
  headers =   {
      'x-requested-with':'XMLHttpRequest',
      'Cookie': 'sessionid=8tjkos13k0wpd9rzje3xcc8dp1v64kug; __cf_bm=kbWudR66vyTEyth2CjVopfXLfOA167E8Yk9iDbeWj9E-1708936562-1.0-AUMLR7tUp64sdzNeaVPMSqvEnR6OAF51OY2DP6PhyH2N2DoH3WgQ5VWAlM/nK0YXJUTj+ZRXojZ/mFoXSJN1fG4=; _dist=pc%7Cat%7CUSD%7CFalse%7CFalse; csrftoken=QKKDI9DJijqDPqZNxSb1nZX4S8OL42me; _vis_opt_s=1%7C; _vis_opt_test_cookie=1; _vwo_uuid=JD54AA9370AC4D52B053FB35FD1C85A99; _vwo_ds=3%241708936564%3A65.47499426%3A%3A; ssUserId=de191604-36fd-4a4f-9104-fbbdcf6fe231; _isuid=de191604-36fd-4a4f-9104-fbbdcf6fe231; _vwo_uuid_v2=D09233018FAFE283F98683391374FBCE0|2674009931fdff7a4795c686321c68ed; atatus-aid=id|e58b15cdc83046e49cc2a955b99fefc5&timestamp|2024-02-26T08:36:05.118Z; _gcl_au=1.1.311801418.1708936565; tkbl_cvuuid=e9e07924-d9ab-4e8b-80ae-62c4be6284d7; NaN; cyo_shape=; cartCount=0; be_rep=false; be_symbol=USD; be_f=p; wlCount=0; rskxRunCookie=0; rCookie=dzeon27uts3xvdkizp1e6lt2opigo; OptanonAlertBoxClosed=2024-02-26T08:36:07.703Z; _mpacs=y; _bamAttribution=%7B%22gclid%22%3A%22%22%2C%22source%22%3A%22%28direct%29%22%2C%22campaign%22%3A%22%28direct%29%22%2C%22medium%22%3A%22%28none%29%22%2C%22keyword%22%3A%22%22%2C%22content%22%3A%22%22%2C%22date%22%3A%2220240226%22%7D; __utmz=11288170.1708936567.1.1.utmcsr%3D%28direct%29%7Cutmccn%3D%28direct%29%7Cutmcmd%3D%28none%29; _cs_mk_ga=0.5318477980920424_1708936567733; _li_dcdm_c=.brilliantearth.com; _lc2_fpi=6fb155432e4e--01hqj8x76a1sef92faajeg2mdv; _lc2_fpi_meta={%22w%22:1708936568010}; _gid=GA1.2.601193034.1708936568; _cs_c=0; wurfl=%7B%22complete_device_name%22%3A%22Google%20Chrome%22%2C%22form_factor%22%3A%22Desktop%22%2C%22is_mobile%22%3Afalse%7D; _nb_sp_ses.8341=*; LPVID=k2ZDQzMmE4YWY4MjE0YjQx; LPSID-28108963=uv-5K3DIRk6Je-mmxaSN-A; __rtbh.uid=%7B%22eventType%22%3A%22uid%22%2C%22id%22%3A%22undefined%22%7D; __rtbh.lid=%7B%22eventType%22%3A%22lid%22%2C%22id%22%3A%22ReYfRBtI3t6F6GKAqQhC%22%7D; IR_gbd=brilliantearth.com; __pdst=695c2b26e84546a4afb14ea258c64ebb; sa-user-id=s%253A0-9d89ace7-a469-5187-7b79-5d6182a5e58f.zB6NsxnOmZu%252BbTIDQ58D5D7rjxwdnncBHIk0ao4a0mU; sa-user-id-v2=s%253AnYms56RpUYd7eV1hgqXljylCYAE.LhCzFOflL17%252FKUFI2Gox7wFZpLDGlqq7wgYmuKQH470; sa-user-id-v3=s%253AAQAKIKFWtzj1ZsrmOW1G74Ktn3CYIFz579xmDWT3NZsAKqkIEHwYBCC3yp2qBjABOgRrkJNFQgRc-Bfg.7QGWzkDvUHGoHhKUmnfDezeE6LB522xcqxSosrfKcAU; _tt_enable_cookie=1; _ttp=zBx-OAnc20baRY40NqYQv_8i1i8; _fbp=fb.1.1708936632968.1778099912; FPID=FPID2.2.s8fmXfEFRjAaSNZCvTz0eowChl5gt2gBIPNtiicOrGY%3D.1708936568; FPAU=1.1.311801418.1708936565; _scid=9c4fc9b7-d370-44c8-bffd-3a3f323d8080; FPLC=LOvTg0bWJWBoAk7Us4m6pSbl7EFJshMqrllCCe0M0qMipk6z%2F6Ixi8pAYKyyGpR6wqoS6aPYV3xn%2BFeavui9VFSomy8kjhwteGD%2B51wQnelsCsJAI6mCvoPoiWux1w%3D%3D; _pin_unauth=dWlkPU1ETTNZekpqWlRndE5UWmhOQzAwWVdKakxUaGtObUl0TW1WbVpqRTVZVE01T0dVeA; __attentive_id=d493ac2e98f845d78d4b6bf302c78b02; _attn_=eyJ1Ijoie1wiY29cIjoxNzA4OTM2NjM0OTAyLFwidW9cIjoxNzA4OTM2NjM0OTAyLFwibWFcIjoyMTkwMCxcImluXCI6ZmFsc2UsXCJ2YWxcIjpcImQ0OTNhYzJlOThmODQ1ZDc4ZDRiNmJmMzAyYzc4YjAyXCJ9In0=; __attentive_cco=1708936634905; __attentive_ss_referrer=ORGANIC; __attentive_dv=1; ABTastySession=mrasn=&lp=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.brilliantearth.com%252Fdiamond%252Fshop-all%252F; bluecoreNV=false; ABTasty=uid=8302ae3brdbbs1ka&fst=1708936564165&pst=-1&cst=1708936564165&ns=1&pvt=5&pvis=5&th=; _vwo_sn=0%3A5; ssSessionIdNamespace=bf9d8632-4dca-4c0f-8f94-e23423d38cf6; sailthru_pageviews=5; OptanonConsent=isGpcEnabled=0&datestamp=Mon+Feb+26+2024+09%3A37%3A44+GMT%2B0100+(Mitteleurop%C3%A4ische+Normalzeit)&version=202209.2.0&isIABGlobal=false&hosts=&consentId=1c7e67ff-944e-491f-88c9-0aec95fcae55&interactionCount=1&landingPath=NotLandingPage&groups=C0001%3A1%2CC0002%3A1%2CC0003%3A1%2CC0004%3A1&geolocation=AT%3B9&AwaitingReconsent=false; _rdt_uuid=1708936632338.e572b8ed-d53d-48bf-a7ba-f399bd63f6f8; _scid_r=9c4fc9b7-d370-44c8-bffd-3a3f323d8080; mp_brilliant_earth_mixpanel=%7B%22distinct_id%22%3A%20%2218de48e9421551-05c22383cb151f-26001951-1fa400-18de48e942210cf%22%2C%22bc_persist_updated%22%3A%201708936565806%2C%22country_code%22%3A%20%22us%22%7D; IR_13541=1708936664426%7C0%7C1708936664426%7C%7C; _uetsid=3d02a960d48211ee9fa73743dd272beb; _uetvid=3d02d2a0d48211ee96f861403df819e6; sailthru_content=070b89718411939d45e45d4a4e8ec3f8db7de6e593badaa3a5e20d61bff846e5; sailthru_visitor=e459df5d-15e0-4f3b-99f8-5ade47e0474c; cto_bundle=DQpw_l9BWklLMTdrbEM0SmJ2TiUyQjVHJTJGNHBDU0NtcTRNaEJWeHRLNXoybllrNEM5dTRFcWNvJTJCJTJGTVBib1ZRd1ZKMyUyQkwlMkJ2VnV3JTJGc0R0Mmt1WjZrQTBKRzBZNFV3bkc4JTJGbTdjUzQ3THNxb3pSSHRtTXJ1UldWc2JWbmpDdHBXckZUWWp2S0lBeFdrYkQzV2FPZDBQYXF4Mk12Mk9mbE5ydDMzV2Z3JTJGYllGOHNtY0htbTQlM0Q; _derived_epik=dj0yJnU9cHc1d3BpYTAwUnFkMXBnT3hOOHJuX1ZwYzBIRFJPc0Mmbj1rcGdKN3J2eDJrbDhzVXRYSkl3czR3Jm09MSZ0PUFBQUFBR1hjVGRnJnJtPTEmcnQ9QUFBQUFHWGNUZGcmc3A9Mg; __attentive_pv=4; atatus-sid=id|b5f9daeb9d544730ac6de3a2986630b0&timestamp|2024-02-26T08:37:45.413Z; _ga=GA1.2.2045111530.1708936568; lastRskxRun=1708936665496; RUM_EPISODES=s=1708936666476&r=https%3A//www.brilliantearth.com/diamond/shop-all/; _ga_123456=GS1.1.1708936632.1.1.1708936666.0.0.0; cf_chl_3=9c8b8b78037c98e; cf_clearance=SLxHGRS8AYg9tAcmN4M3UqKMqvPDqxIFirjMk.9RELM-1708936786-1.0-AUeQqx5zUdAPFqeeA37P41IM3hlqfz3mxBCla1KEodLjmR9QCoAX4AbIxmA61H2Z+XmRrwmdMJc5LaVv2Yf2XDs=; _cs_id=27513c55-41b2-a60b-d123-7083081613df.1708936568.1.1708937244.1708936568.1.1743100568221.1; _cs_s=6.0.0.1708939044676; _nb_sp_id.8341=0684837f-b168-4ac5-8292-ed3c261b76b2.1708936568.1.1708937385.1708936568.376c17c2-df7e-47f8-9af7-5c2cf8b9602b; _dd_s=rum=0&expire=1708938289392; _gat=1; _ga_M6K9G20MZ3=GS1.1.1708936575.1.1.1708937389.0.0.0; ld_lcd_params=shapes%3DAll%7Cclarities%3DSI2%2CSI1%2CVS2%2CVS1%2CVVS2%2CVVS1%2CIF%2CFL%7Ccuts%3DFair%2CGood%2CVery%20Good%2CIdeal%2CSuper%20Ideal',
      'Referer': 'https://www.brilliantearth.com/diamond/shop-all/'
      }

  url = "https://www.brilliantearth.com/loose-diamonds/list/?shapes=All&cuts=Fair%2CGood%2CVery%20Good%2CIdeal%2CSuper%20Ideal&colors=J%2CI%2CH%2CG%2CF%2CE%2CD&clarities=SI2%2CSI1%2CVS2%2CVS1%2CVVS2%2CVVS1%2CIF%2CFL&polishes=Good%2CVery%20Good%2CExcellent&symmetries=Good%2CVery%20Good%2CExcellent&fluorescences=Very%20Strong%2CStrong%2CMedium%2CFaint%2CNone&min_carat=0.25&max_carat=10.21&min_table=48.00&max_table=88.00&min_depth=3.50&max_depth=90.70&min_price=340&max_price=1062110&stock_number=&row=0&page=1&requestedDataSize=50&currency=%24&has_v360_video=&dedicated=&min_ratio=1.00&max_ratio=2.75&shipping_day=&suppler_shipping_day=&exclude_quick_ship_suppliers=&MIN_PRICE=380&MAX_PRICE=332150&MIN_CARAT=0.25&MAX_CARAT=10.21&MIN_TABLE=48&MAX_TABLE=88&MIN_DEPTH=3.5&MAX_DEPTH=90.7&order_by=&order_method=&category=Loose%20Diamonds&fill_most_popular=true&most_popular_order_by=&most_popular_order_method="
  resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
  print(resp.status_code)
```

But i allways get a 403-statuscode as response?
When i put the url directly in the chrome-browser (also in incognito mode) i see the data in the browser - see attached[image]

Why is the request not working?

Comment: Try again with `User-Agent` header.

Comment: It seems that the anti-bot is blocking you, as abdul advised, you should consider using `User-Agent` : https://www.zenrows.com/blog/python-requests-user-agent#what-is

Comment: adding the User-Agent helped - now i get a status 200
if you want you can send me that as answer and i will accept